# Cannot access Ubuntu Samba share from Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, ubuntu, virtual-machine, samba

Host: Windows 10
Guest: 2x Ubuntu 16.04
VM: Virtualbox
Networking: host-only adapter

I cannot use bridged mode because my company's network won't assign an IP address to the VMs.

I set up Samba on Ubuntu-VM-1 and I'm able to access the Samba share from Ubuntu-VM-2.

However, from Windows I cannot access the Samba share.

Status:
* Ping between all guests and host
* Mount samba share of Ubuntu-VM-1 in Ubuntu-VM-2
* I can see Ubuntu-VM-1 from Windows: \192.168.56.101 but the share doesn't show up

In Windows **Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings** I've set all the settings to the most permissive modes.

Comment: Have you tried typing in the Samba server's IP in Explorer to access the share (`\\192.168.1.2\share\name`)?  Windows 10 will not show Samba servers in Explorer unless you've correctly configured static DNS entries within the host file and DNS server, coupled w/ setting the same local domain/workgroup name, or have mapped the share. Have you verified what SMB version the Samba server is using?  Try setting minimum and maximum values to `SMB2` within `smb.conf` _(note: SMB1 **should not** be utilized)_.  Have you reviewed the Samba logs to determine if any errors are being generated?

Comment: Yes I'm using the actually IP. The problem is a Windows problem: I can access the share from the other Ubuntu-VM.

Comment: @JW0914 you've typed a lot of conditions so let's take one at a time. Version is `Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu`

Comment: @JW0914 I set the min and max `protocol` to `SMB2` but still doesn't work.

Comment: More likely than not, the issue resides within the `smb.conf` options set and/or a DNS/networking issue.  This requires troubleshooting that's more beneficial on a forum and is where I personally would recommend going for troubleshooting.  Logs and the smb.conf are likely going to be required to post, and currently, this is way too open-ended to efficiently troubleshoot here.

Comment: @JW0914 I set it to `SMB2`. The issue is Windows: I can view the SAMBA share from the other Ubuntu VM but in Windows, I can "view" the computer by typing `\\192.168.56.101` into Explorer but no shares appear.

Comment: Right, Windows doesn't handle Samba shares and networking in the same way as Linux, with there being a few caveats when it comes to Windows.  IIRC, when I was using Ubuntu 16 3 years ago, I had to create a separate Windows user to log in to Samba shares served via Ubuntu, as it was the simplest and most efficient option at the time.  I don't recall the troubleshooting I did, as shortly thereafter I bypassed the issue entirely by [configuring `xrdp`](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8952) for remote desktop, which I've used on every version up to the most recent (v19).